# Extract embedded vecor per word from h2o.word2vec object

Tags: python, r, nlp, h2o

I'm trying to create a pre-trained embedding layer, using `h2o.word2vec`, i'm looking to extract each word in the model and its equivalent embedded vector.

Code:

```
library(data.table)
library(h2o)
h2o.init(nthreads = -1)

comment <- data.table(comments='ExplanationWhy the edits made under my username Hardcore Metallica 
                      Fan were reverted They werent vandalisms just closure on some GAs after I voted 
                      at New York Dolls FAC And please dont remove the template from the talk page since Im retired now')

comments.hex <- as.h2o(comment, destination_frame = "comments.hex", col.types=c("String"))

words <- h2o.tokenize(comments.hex$comments, "\\\\W+")

vectors <- 3 # Only 10 vectors to save time & memory
w2v.model <- h2o.word2vec(words
                          , model_id = "w2v_model"
                          , vec_size = vectors
                          , min_word_freq = 1
                          , window_size = 2
                          , init_learning_rate = 0.025
                          , sent_sample_rate = 0
                          , epochs = 1) # only a one epoch to save time
print(h2o.findSynonyms(w2v.model, "the",2))
```

The `h2o` API enables me to get the cosine of two word, but i'm just looking to get the vector of each work in my vocabulary, how can i get it? couldn't find any simple method in the API that gives it

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the method `w2v_model.transform(words=words)`

(complete options are: `w2v_model.transform(words =, aggregate_method =)`

where `words` is an H2O Frame made of a single column containing source words (Note that you can specify to include a subset of this frame) and `aggregate_method` specifies how to aggregate sequences of words.

if you don't specify an aggregation method, then no aggregation is performed, and each input word is mapped to a single word-vector. If the method is AVERAGE, then the input is treated as sequences of words delimited by NA.

For example:

```
av_vecs = w2v_model.transform(words, aggregate_method = "AVERAGE")
```

Comment: Here's a link to the Word2Vec user guide that provides additional info: http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/word2vec.html#transforming-words-to-vectors